# How to apply media queries to ng-repeat table

Tags: angularjs, media-queries, angular-material

I have the following table I require it to display appropriately on mobile/tablet. I would like to kinda display the hour column and availability column for each day by day down the scroll.

[image]

```
 <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="week">
            <th></th>
            <th class="day">Wednesday 18th</th>
            <th class="day">Thursday  19th</th>
            <th class="day">Friday    20th</th>
            <th class="day">Saturday  21st</th>
            <th class="day">Monday    23rd</th>
            <th class="day">Tuesday   24th</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="hour in workhours" ng-init="selectedIndex=$index">
            <td >{{hour}}:00 - {{hour+1}}:00</td>

            <td ng-class = "{ 'full'     : !entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour),
                              'selected' : renderGreen(selectedIndex, $index, jobLength)}" 
                ng-click = "checkSlotAvailability(hour, jobLength, entry, data)"
                ng-repeat= "entry in data.calendar">

                    <span ng-if="entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour)">
                        Available
                    </span>
                    <span ng-if="!entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour)">
                        Full
                    </span>
                    <span ng-if="entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour) && renderGreen(selectedIndex, $index, jobLength)">
                        Selected
                    </span>
                    <span ng-if="entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour) && !renderGreen(selectedIndex, $index, jobLength) && selectedIndex==selectedRow && $index==selectedColumn"> 
                        {{ data.response }}
                    </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm getting all sorts of weird rendering's on chrome mobile dev tools. Any help is welcome.

Comment: you can use bootstrap css framework for applying media queries to your application

Comment: with `col-xs-12` or `col-sm-12` type of classes? I've tried all that but it's not working or rather rendering weirdly. Tried various column numbers 1, 2, 4 6,etc

Comment: please check http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables , bootstrap has provided responsive utilities for table as well

Comment: for this your may wrap table inside div having class `col-xs-12`; however you may get horizontal scroll for table.

Comment: that's what I'm trying to get rid of. horizontal scrolling. I've placed the table in `.table-responsive` div as well.

Comment: There is no straightforward solution for making table responsive; You may need add filter on your table; likewise what datatable offers;So in desktop every column is visible and in mobile only few columns will be visible.

Comment: sure thanks for the info

Comment: shall i post this as answer or you want to keep the thread open ?

Comment: post as answer i guess. got some info from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Bootstrap table utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) for making table responsive ; however if you have many numbers of columns then you might experienced horizontal scroll in mobile view.

To tackle this issue you can implement custom filters in a table for which in desktop view all columns will be visible and for mobile few columns will be visible.

**EDIT**

Please give a try to [this](https://github.com/awerlang/angular-responsive-tables) solution. This might help though

Hope this helps you.